# X has no attribute 'object' - Django

Tags: django, object, model

I am following a tutorial about how to build a social network in Django.

I have built this view:

```
class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse("groups:single",kwargs={"slug": self.kwargs.get("slug")})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group,slug=self.kwargs.get("slug"))

        try:
            GroupMember.object.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)

        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(self.request,("Warning, already a member of {}".format(group.name)))

        else:
            messages.success(self.request,"You are now a member of the {} group.".format(group.name))

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But when I try to access its url, I get (from console):

> my_path\simplesocial\groups\views.py", line 40, in get
>       GroupMember.object.create(user=self.request.user, group=group) AttributeError: type object 'GroupMember' has no attribute 'object'

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in this line:

```
GroupMember.object.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)
```

the method to create a new object in a model is not `.object.create` but `.objects.create`

Then the correct line should be:

```
GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)
```

Answer (score -1):

The line should be:

```
GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)
```